# How to transfer ifelse code segment by OOP?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I know that I should break down the method by condition, and implement interface to each subclass, but I do not know how does the client class use it, can you give me simple sample?

```
 public void buildInfoItemUpdater() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.projectInfoInputItemUpdaters.size(); i++) {
        if (this.projectInfoInputItemUpdaters.get(i) instanceof ComboBoxUpdater) {
            ComboBoxUpdater tempItem = (ComboBoxUpdater) this.projectInfoInputItemUpdaters.get(i);
            projectInfoInputItemUpdaters.get(i).setAnswer(tempItem.getUserAnswer());
        } else if (this.projectInfoInputItemUpdaters.get(i) instanceof TextBoxUpdater) {
            TextBoxUpdater tempItem = (TextBoxUpdater) this.projectInfoInputItemUpdaters.get(i);
            projectInfoInputItemUpdaters.get(i).setAnswer(tempItem.getUserAnswer());
        } else if (this.projectInfoInputItemUpdaters.get(i) instanceof TextFieldUpdater) {
            TextFieldUpdater tempItem = (TextFieldUpdater) this.projectInfoInputItemUpdaters.get(i);
            projectInfoInputItemUpdaters.get(i).setAnswer(tempItem.getUserAnswer());
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are the *Updater classes defined? Do they have a common base class? Could you add the getUserAnswer method to that base class?

Comment: This question may be a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @SirPentor, nice suggestion, I was think along the same lines. I added a code example in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As suggested by @SirPentor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695098/how-to-transfer-ifelse-code-segment-by-oop/10697911#comment13884384_10695098), if the Updater classes have a common base class (lets call it UpdaterBase), then define the getUserAnswer() method there, most likely as abstract.

Then you could simplify buildInfoItemUpdater() as follows:

```
public void buildInfoItemUpdater() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.projectInfoInputItemUpdaters.size(); i++) {
        UpdaterBase tempItem =
              (UpdaterBase) this.projectInfoInputItemUpdaters.get(i);
        projectInfoInputItemUpdaters.get(i).setAnswer(tempItem.getUserAnswer());
    }
}
```

Additionally, whats the difference between `this.projectInfoInputItemUpdaters.get(i)` and `projectInfoInputItemUpdaters.get(i)`? Seems like your calling get() twice on the same object, right? You may be able to simplify this part as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, and I got a solution that using "State Pattern".